# Could not load type 'User control'

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint-2010

I have restored a site in sharepoint 2010. But when I run it, it pops the error about the user control. 
i.e.

```
Could not load type 'Newsletter.Web.Applications.Subscribers.AddSubscriberStep1'.
```

Here is the error description from LOG:

```
System.Web.HttpException: Could not load type 'Newsletter.Web.Applications.Subscribers.AddSubscriberStep1'.    at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly)     at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)   ac3fc84c-11f3-46a0-bea5-930c43627627
```

I have deployed the project where that user control resides but still the same error. Where am I going wrong? Kindly assist me.

Answer (score 3):

The following example shows that for a Web UserControl, but it works the same for a Page, a Master Page and a WebPart:

```
  <!-- change this (ASP.NET Web Site version) -->
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeFile="WebUserControl.ascx.cs"
 Inherits="Controls_WebUserControl" %>

 <!-- into this (ASP.NET Web Application version), or vice versa -->
 <%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
 CodeBehind="WebUserControl.ascx.cs"
 Inherits="Controls_WebUserControl" %>
```

That’s all you need to do to get rid of that annoying error!

The reason? If you have an “ASP.NET Web Application”, Microsoft needs CodeBehind in the Page, Control or Master directive, if you have an “ASP.NET Web Site”, the compiler expects CodeFile instead. I have no idea why this difference exists, it is very annoying and you can stare forever at your code before you find it, but this is the solution for this scenario