# How to use user controls in asp.net web form's header section

Tags: asp.net

I have multiple asp.net web form pages which use the same css files and CDNs. Since I can't use Master pages, due to internal restrictions, I have created a user control I used it in the Header section of the pages. However, I am getting Could not load type 'OrderProcessing.UserControls.Shared.ConfirmationCDNs'..error. I was able to use another user control in the body section without a problem.

```
The ascx file:
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="GiftDeliveryConfirmationCDNs.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="MyOrderProcessing.UserControls.Shared.ConfirmationCDNs" %>
    <link href="../../Styles/mysite.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="../../Styles/mysite_Confirmation.css" rel="stylesheet" />



    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script 
  src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
  </script>



    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script 
 src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>

In the aspx file:
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
CodeBehind="Confirmation.aspx.cs" Inherits="MyOrderProcessing.Confirmation" 
%>

<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/Shared/ConfirmationCDNs.ascx" 
TagPrefix="uc1" TagName="ConfirmationCDNs" %>



<!DOCTYPE html>

<html> 
<head>
   <title>Confirmation</title>      
   <uc1:ConfirmationCDNs runat="server" id="ConfirmationCDNs" /> 
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">            
</head>
```

Comment: It seems there is a problem on how you're registering the User Control. It depends on wheter the App is ASP.Net Web Site or ASP.Net Web Application, to use the Keyword CodeFile instead of CodeBehind. Take a look at this similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841669/could-not-load-type-user-control

Comment: At the first glance `<head>` tag doesn't have `runat="server"` attribute, is it intentional (usually an ASPX page has `<head runat="server">`)? Probably the `<head>` tag doesn't have user control support like `<body>` tag has.